# Windows Form, Z-coordinate

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my application I have problem with some windows forms. They are sometimes fell down under another window.

Is there some Z-coordinate for Form? Or how is this working?

Thank you.

EDIT: I should add, that I'm using Smart Client Software Factory.

Comment: There is a z order, but I believe that for the most part that is just the order that you add them to the form, you can select one then I believe under edit there is bring forward, **Edit** thought question was about controls... you can declare a parent in your Show(Dialog)() that should resolve this

Comment: Do you own the "other" windows?

Comment: yes, I do own them. They are created for me from Smart Client Software Factory.

Comment: If you want to force the window to stay on top, use `myForm.TopMost = true;`, but I would not recommend that.

Comment: Yes, I'm using this as a workaround. But I'm not happy with that.

Comment: wherever your opening the dialogs try using `Show(this)` or `ShowDialog(this)` I would test an answer but not got the time right now

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Form.Show(IWin32Window owner)` method to spawn a form as a child of another form, which will always keep it above that form.

For example:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show(this);
    }
}

class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

When an instance of  `Form1` is created, it will create and show an instance of the `Form2` class as a child. `Form1` will be behind `Form2` regardless of which form has focus.

EDIT: I took some screenshots of the effect, complete with labels that responded to the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events of each form to demonstrate in case the lovely blue border wasn't enough:

[image]